# group by nodes or deleting nodes repeated with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, delete-row

I have been researching how to delete repeated nodes but not how to proceed.

I have this initial list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SEC count="7">
    <value>outy</value>
    <name>object</name>
    <Row>
<client>0000000530708</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <client>0000000530708</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <client>0000000999999</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <client>0000000999999</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <client>0000000999999</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
</SEC>
```

and I would like to get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SEC count="7">
    <value>outy</value>
    <name>object</name>
    <Row>
        <client>0000000530708</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <client>0000000999999</client>
        <date>20100401</date>
    </Row>
</SEC>
```

how can I do it?
Someone can help me?. I  use XSL 1.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variation on the Muenchian method for this. Start with an identity template to copy everything as-is except where overridden by a more specific template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Define a *key* giving the uniqueness condition:

```
<xsl:key name="uniqueRow" match="Row" use="concat(client, '|', date)"/>
```

and add one more template to ignore any `Row` that is *not* the first one with that particular key value:

```
<xsl:template match="Row[generate-id() !=
  generate-id(key('uniqueRow', concat(client, '|', date))[1])]"/>
```